# How does one make an image path fetched from mongodb work in react project?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, multer

I saved an image path to mongodb and now when I am using it in react as image source the image appears to be broken.

In uploads controller I create a post that has an avatar property that creates the path of the image:

**upload.js**

```
exports.uploadAvatar = async (req, res) => {
    const url = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}`; 
    const { title, content } = req.body;

    const newPost = new Post({
        title,
        content,
        avatar: `${url}/client/src/uploads/${req.file.filename}`,
    });
    
    await newPost.save((error, post) => {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                status: false,
                message: error,
            });
        }
        
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'File is uploaded.',
            post: {
                avatar: post.avatar
            }
        });
    });
};
```

In routes I am passing the multer middleware to uploadAvatar controller and also make the multer configurations:

**routes.js**

```
const multer = require('multer');
    const { uploadAvatar } = require('../controllers/upload');
    
    const FILE_PATH = 'client/src/uploads';
    
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, FILE_PATH),
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
            const fileName = file.originalname.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');
            cb(null, `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}-${fileName}`); 
        },
    });
    
    const upload = multer({storage: storage});
    
    
    router.post('/upload-avatar', upload.single('avatar'), uploadAvatar);
```

Then in App.js I get the post and populate profileImg state variable with the path of the image which comes from mongodb object avatar property.

**App.js**

```
export default () => {
    const [profileImg, setProfileImg] = React.useState([]);
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/get-avatar`)
            .then(res => {
                setProfileImg(res.data.posts[0]);
                // console.log(res.data.posts[0])
            })
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <div className="avatar">
            <img src={profileImg.avatar} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

**mongodb document**

```
{
    "avatar":"http://localhost:8080/client/src/uploads/5914-irina.jpg",
    "title":"Lorem Ipsum",
    "content":"ed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste.",
}
```

**Project structure**

```
client
    public
    src
        uploads
            // my image
        App.js
        index.js
controllers
models
routes
server
pachage.json
```

The problem is that the image in react component does not show and in console I get this error:

> GET http://localhost:8080/client/src/uploads/some-image.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 2):

i faced the same issue. I solved it in a very simple way though i am not sure whether it's a perfect way of implementation or not.
According to react the root directory start from public and for rendering any dynamic image, that image should be kept in public folder. So I stored the images in **"client/public/images"** folder.

so my image src was like this

```
<img src={`http://localhost:3000/images/${imageName}`} alt=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `uploads` folder into the `public` folder then change your avatar URL like this

```
{
   "avatar":"/uploads/5914-irina.jpg",
}
```

or

```
{
   "avatar":"http://localhost:8080/uploads/5914-irina.jpg",
}
```

Comment: On which port does the client listning ?

Comment: On port 3000 and server on 8080

Comment: Your images are on the client side so after moving the `uploads` folder into the `public` the URL should be `http://localhost:3000/uploads/5914-irina.jpg`

Comment: Your solution makes sense to me as well, and it should work but it doesn't.
The path stored in mongo is "client/public/uploads/477471-dem.jpg" and in App.js I have <img src={`http://localhost:3000/${profileImage}`} /> and  the uploads forlder is in root/client/public/uploads. I guess I'll keep tweaking thing around until I'll get it right, hopefully. But thanks for your response.

Comment: In mongoDB, `{avatar: "/uploads/477471-dem.jpg" }` then in App.js `<img src={profileImage.avatar} />`, that should do the trick